# how to find duplicates based on column value in pandas df.trying get o/p if unique_id is same for ann_id check for how many duplicate entries

Tags: pandas

my df looks similar to below.

```
ann_id        unique_id   start     end
1               apple       0       1
1               apple       2       3
1               apple       4       5
1               apple       6       7
2               apple       0       1
2               apple       2       3
2               apple       4       5
2               apple       60      7
1               apple       22      33
1               apple       44      55
1               mango       33      66
1               mango       77      88
1               mango       99      89
2               orange      11      22
2               orange      30      40
2               orange      50      60
```

my expected o/p:

```
ann_id        unique_id   start     end
1               apple       0       1
1               apple       2       3
1               apple       4       5
2               apple       0       1
2               apple       2       3
2               apple       4       5
```

iam trying get o/p if unique_id is same for ann_id check for how many duplicate entries

Comment: here we are checking exact match in start and end if unique_id matches

Comment: it is not continous it is a random number.Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try creating a boolean index with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas-dataframe-duplicated):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ann_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'unique_id': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple',
                  'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'mango', 'mango', 'mango',
                  'orange', 'orange', 'orange'],
    'start': [0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 2, 4, 60, 22, 44, 33, 77, 99, 11, 30, 50],
    'end': [1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7, 33, 55, 66, 88, 89, 22, 40, 60]
})

output = df[df.duplicated(subset=['unique_id', 'start', 'end'], keep=False)]
print(output)
```

`output`:

```
   ann_id unique_id  start  end
0       1     apple      0    1
1       1     apple      2    3
2       1     apple      4    5
4       2     apple      0    1
5       2     apple      2    3
6       2     apple      4    5
```